# Поиск закономерности в строках

Tags: алгоритм, валидация

Есть массив кодов (несколько рандомных букв и за ними несколько рандомных цифр).

Есть некий алгоритм, который проверяет валидность (как к примеру в банковских картах). Но он не известен.

Есть ли какие-то стандартные алгоритмы проверки закономерности? К примеру суммирование значений символов и другое. Возможно есть программа которая это делает. Точно знаем что в массиве все коды валидные.

---

Вообще речь идет о кодах акции внутри упаковок (таких есть много) С интереса решил поискать лазейки и узнать как работает. Фишингом добыл 70 кодов и теперь хочу узнать какой алгоритм используют. И есть ли он вообще (должна быть какая-то антиспам система).

Дисклеймер: конечно же не использую в свою пользу, все ради интереса и пользователи которые попались получили сообщение что это эксперимент, их код использовать не будут и ссылку на оригинальный ресурс.

Comment: А какого размера код и сколько есть гарантированно валидных кодов?

Comment: @S.H. ну я так понимаю чем меньше размер и чем больше экземпляров то больше шанс?) 7 лат. букв, а за ними 5 цифр. Пока что 70 валидных есть

Comment: Об алгоритме генерации хоть что-то известно?

Comment: @Chorkov нет, только список валидных кодов

Comment: Боюсь, тогда Вам поможет только самый мощный нейропроцесссор - человеческий мозг... если бы кол-вол валидных кодов измерядлось миллиардами - можно было бы нейроночку натравить. Но я должен Вас разочаровать: в по настоящему серьезных местах всякие проверочные и скидочные коды генерируются ГСЧ.

Comment: Давайте сюда ваши коды. Может чей-нибудь нейропроцессор найдёт закономерность. Коды мы конечно же использовать в свою пользу не будем, всё ради интереса, это эксперимент.

Comment: @S.H. да, скорее всего так и есть. Но мне было интересно есть ли что-то подобное, т.к. может пригодится во многих сферах

Comment: @wololo это было сделано фишингом, пользователи думали что код регистрируют, потом только узнавали:) Думаю розыгрыш машины (" ") это не лучшее на чем можно заработать обманом)

Comment: Мне кажется тут только нагенерить разных гипотез и потом их проверять. В банковских картах по первым цифрам можно узнать вроде банк и регион, т.е. они генерятся не по принципу, а вообще из справочника, а в целом там какая-то контрольная сумма ещё должна сойтись. Так что не знаю, сложновато будет с нуля такое придумать. Но придумать алгоритм, под который подпадут известные коды, наверное, можно.